# Clarify definition of exported identifier

Tags: go

What is the rationale of the [Go specification to define an identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) as exported

> if both:
>
> 1. the first character of the identifier's name is a Unicode upper case letter (Unicode class "Lu"); and
> 2. the identifier is declared in the package block or it is a field name or method name. "

The item 1. is clear to me.

But what is the intended meaning of the item 2. ?

As I understand every identifier must be declared in the package block, as Go does not offer other places to declare identifiers.
I also do not understand why the sentence seems to distinguish between identifiers and field names and method names. Aren't field names and method names examples of identifiers?

To ask differently: am I wrong thinking that:

1. there is no other way for an identifier to come to exist except
   being declared in a package block (note [a package block encompasses all package code](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blocks))
2. field names and method names are identifiers
3. Identifiers are declarable solely in the package block
4. No identifier be declared outside a package block

Comment: "Is there any other way for an identifier to come to exist except being declared in a package block?" Yes, of course. Local variables in a function or method, for instance. ["Identifiers name program entities such as variables and types."](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Identifiers) Types can be declared in functions too, they need not be in the package block.

Comment: @Peter: I do not think this is a good example. All entities you name are still in 'package block'. See the definition of 'package block' at https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blocks : "Each package has a package block containing all Go source text for that package."

Comment: "Go source text" is not synonymous with "all identifiers", though. The ["Declarations and scope"](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope) section describes in detail how identifiers are bound to blocks. For instance: "5. The scope of a constant or variable identifier declared inside a function begins at the end of the ConstSpec or VarSpec [...] _and ends at the end of the innermost containing block_."

Comment: "No identifier may be declared twice in the same block." If your understanding was correct you could never use the same variable name twice, because they would conflict in the universe block. That's clearly not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Identifiers include struct field names and method names.

As denoted in the [struct types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) section:

> Field names may be specified explicitly (IdentifierList) or implicitly
> (EmbeddedField)

In the following struct:

```
type s struct {
  A int
  b int
}
```

`A` is exported since it is a field name and starts with an uppercase character. `b` is not since it is a field name, but does not start with an uppercase character.

The same goes for method names (eg: `(_ s) DoA()` vs `(_ s) doB()`).

The confusion stems from the fact that you think identifiers are only at the package block level: they are not.

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer. 
Could you elaborate what you mean with 'block level' here? If you mean something around 'blocks of code surrounded by '}', '{', like e.g. function body or for/if constructs' - then no, I do not limit my thinking to these. I also consider e.g. package-level variables.
BTW: in your example structure declaration you have used *some* block (delimited with '}', '{') - despite that you seem to suggest that block-level thinking is too narrow here.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. There is no other way for an identifier to come to exist except being declared in a package block

That's true. One thing that you're missing is [scope](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope) of identifiers:

> The scope of a constant or variable identifier declared inside a function begins at the end of the ConstSpec or VarSpec (ShortVarDecl for short variable declarations) and ends at the end of the innermost containing block

Which means that identifier declared inside function block, will not be available outside of this function.

#### 2. Field names and method names are identifiers

True. As you can see in spec, [`MethodName`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#MethodName) is just an alias to `identifier`, same with [field names](https://golang.org/ref/spec#FieldName).

#### 3. Identifiers are declarable solely in the package block

I believe it's addressed by answer to 1st question.

#### 4. No identifier can be declared outside a package block

There's [predeclared identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Predeclared_identifiers) that are declared in universe block. But you can't declare identifiers outside of package block in code.